# MonoTouch Dialog - OnTap Not Working

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using the Reflection API for MonoTouch.Dialog.  What I want to accomplish is, when the user selects an item from a list, I want the navigation controller to go back.  I don't want to force the user to click an item, then click the Back button to go back.

However, when trying to use the `OnTap` attribute, my method doesn't get executed.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var demo = new DemoClass();
    var context = new BindingContext(this, demo, "Some Demo");
    var controller = new DialogViewController(context.Root);
    var navController = new UINavigationController(controller);

    window.RootViewController = navController;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}

public void EnumSelected()
{
    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        new UIAlertView("Dialog", "Enum Selected", null, "OK", null).Show();
    });
}
```

**DemoClass**

```
public enum DemoEnum
{
    SomeValue,
    AnotherValue,
    YetAnotherValue
}

public class DemoClass
{
    [OnTap("EnumSelected")]
    public DemoEnum SomeEnum;   
}
```

I know how to navigate back with the navigation controller, but without the `OnTap` working, I can't get that far.  Am I missing something?  Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, you can't.

Enum's (which results in a new RootController and a bunch of RadioElement's) can't have an OnTap set, unless you do it all by hand.

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Reflect.cs#L337

especially, these  bits:

```
csection.Add (new RadioElement (ca != null ? ca.Caption : MakeCaption (fi.Name)));

element = new RootElement (caption, new RadioGroup (null, selected)) { csection };
```

There is no trigger added to the RadioElement. You would need to change it to auto-pop the form - which needs a new/changed RadioElement

https://gist.github.com/3569920

(I can't claim this code - it came from @escoz: https://github.com/escoz/MonoMobile.Forms )

So, if you are using the built-in MT.D, you can't do it. If you don't mind maintaining your own branch (or, submit a pull request back, which is what I need to do for a few things), then this is a fairly good way to go.